# How to copy cells from multiple sheets, that do not exist yet, in on master sheet?

Tags: excel, copy, vba

I am quite inexperienced with macros, but I have a task which is in my opinion awfully hard and couldn't find a solution.. I am certain that you can help me.
Here's the problem:
I have a workbook with 2 unhidden sheets ('sector 1' and 'report') and 1 hidden ('main').

'sector 1' has a Command Button, which inserts a new sheet named 'sector 2' (a copy of 'main') when pressed. If I press the Command Button in 'sector 2', it inserts a new copy of 'main', named 'sector 3' and so on. The second unhidden sheet is named 'report' and the task is to insert as many rows in 'report' as the sectors are eventually, and to copy specific values of cells from all unhidden sheets,
e.g. `in cell *A8* of 'report' should be a copy of *B5* from 'sector 1'; 
     in cell *B8* of 'report' should be a copy of *D46* from 'sector 1';
     in cell *A9* of 'report' should be a copy of *B5* from 'sector 2'; 
     in cell *B9* of 'report' should be a copy of *D46* from 'sector 2'.`

The problem is that these sheets - 'sector 2', 'sector 3', 'sector 4' and so on, should not exist when opening the file, and I need to be able to insert unlimited number of worksheets (respectively sectors). 
Please, help me, I am in a deadlock..

Answer (score 0):

Enter these formulas:

Sheet: Report

```
Range A8: =INDIRECT("'Sector "&ROW(A8)-7&"'!B$5")
Range B8: =INDIRECT("'Sector "&ROW(A8)-7&"'!D$46")
```

Drag down and it will update the sheet reference each row.